# How can I replace all keys of nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
      function renameKeys(obj, newKeys) {
        const keyValues = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
          let newKey = key + "1";
          if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) == false) {
            renameKeys(obj[key], newKeys);
          }
          console.log(newKey, "]", obj[key]);
          return {
            [newKey]: obj[key],
          };
        });
        return Object.assign({}, ...keyValues);
      }

      test = JSON.parse(
        '{"verifying_explanation":
               {"bus_stop":["1234"],
                "elementary_school":["1234"],
                "middle_school":["1234"],
                "high_school":["1234"]
               }
         }'
      );
      console.log(test);
      data = renameKeys(test, this);
      console.log(data);
```

It look like all keys changed in function, but it is not applied . I think because of copy principal.
I have no idea how I can manipulate for keys.
I want to replace all keys so that I apply i18n in my code.

So new key will be somethign like
`let newKey = i18n.$t(key);`
This short code is just for test code.
Please give me some ideas to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your function to create new `key value pairs` and then form an `object` from these. Also, check if the value is an `object`, to recursively rename nested objects -

```js
function renameKeys(obj) {
  const keyValues = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    let newKey = key + "1";
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      value = renameKeys(value);
    }
    return [newKey, value];    
  });
  return Object.fromEntries(keyValues);
}

test = JSON.parse(
'{"verifying_explanation": {"bus_stop": ["1234"],"elementary_school": ["1234"],"middle_school": ["1234"],"high_school": ["1234"]}}'
);
console.log(test);
data = renameKeys(test, this);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return new key-value pair in your function, instead of that, you just need to add new key to obj and delete old one.

```js
function renameKeys(obj, newKeys) {
        Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
          let newKey = key + "1";
          if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) == false) {
            renameKeys(obj[key], newKeys);
          }
          // console.log(newKey, "]", obj[key]);
          obj[newKey]=obj[key];
          delete obj[key];
        });
      }

      test = JSON.parse(
        `{"verifying_explanation":
               {"bus_stop":["1234"],
                "elementary_school":["1234"],
                "middle_school":["1234"],
                "high_school":["1234"]
               }
         }`
      );
      
      console.log(test);
      data = renameKeys(test, this);
      console.log(test);
```

Comment: I have one more question. How is this code works without delete [replace keys example without delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533695/how-to-replace-key-in-nested-object)?

Comment: Regard that this is a recursive method, and look into this line: obj[key] = obj[key].map(obj => renameKeys(obj, newKeys)); It will apply the return value to obj at last.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have less understand about map function