# Recursively replace all occurances of large JSON keys having - to _ character

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json from Google pagespeed api, which needs to be exported to big query. Since BQ doesnt support the keys having - symbol, I must replace all the key names those have - char to _

Please note that I cannot perform a find and replace on entire string as the values need a - char. The json structure can be complex and I understand the only ways to do is by iterating all the keys of nested objects.

I found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

but could not iterate the nested json, as I cannot predetermine the json structure and all that must be dynamically decided Any pointers how to replace all chars would be great

The input JSON is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lFYW26xsPGQp6WU9h6f2-E1bHW-hDIic/view?usp=sharing

```
const replaceKeys = obj => {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map( ([key,value]) => {
      return [
        key.replace("-","_"),
        Array.isArray(value)
          ? value.map(replaceKeys)
          :typeof value == "object"
            ? replaceKeys(value)
            : value
      ];
    }))
}

const result = input.map(replaceKeys);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace all keys of nested object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65420262/how-can-i-replace-all-keys-of-nested-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this transformation both, when you JSON.parse() the data from google, or when you JSON.stringify() the object to send it to big query.

imo. that's the most economical approach, to transform **while** parsing or serializing, instead of first parsing then transforming or first transforming then serializing.

```js
// sources
const obj = {
  "key-with-dashes": [{
    "some-value": 42
  }]
};
const json = JSON.stringify(obj);

// utilities
const includesDash = v => v.includes("-");
const replaceDashInKey = kv => {
  kv[0] = kv[0].replace(/-/g, "_");
  return kv;
}
const cleanupDashesInKeys = (k, v) => {
  if (typeof v === "object" &&
    v !== null &&
    !Array.isArray(v) && 
    Object.keys(v).some(includesDash)
  ) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(v).map(replaceDashInKey))
  }
  // this value has no keys with dashes
  return v;
};

//cleanup keys
console.log("on parse", JSON.parse(json, cleanupDashesInKeys));
console.log("on stringify", JSON.stringify(obj, cleanupDashesInKeys));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: The answer fails while I replace this example json https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lFYW26xsPGQp6WU9h6f2-E1bHW-hDIic/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @CodeGuy how does it fail? just tested it in the console with the JSON you linked. I don't get any errors, I see keys with dashes turned to underscores, but still see dashes in the values. At first glance, it seems to work like a charm

Comment: Here is the code I tested and thge output generated cannot be parsed https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wZsDrDfdy_Ch0ymDXEP-rnuQCaDdnpWM/view?usp=sharing